# VB.net menustrip button

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu, menustrip

I want to create a button that drops down a menustrip when clicked. I was successful in using the menustrip alone with dropdowns but i want to make a button as the main trigger to dropdown the menus. Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't dropdown a MenuStrip, it must be an item in the MenuStrip.  Like the File item that's on every standard menu, use its ShowDropDown() method:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    FileToolStripMenuItem.ShowDropDown()
End Sub
```